# How to color selected rows in GridView in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress, xtragrid

I select all row with follow code  in gridview

**gridView1.SelectAll();**

Now i want to color selected rows in gridview for example blue color.

how can i do it?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are talking about the [DevExpress XtraGrid](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Grid/). If so, then there are multiple approaches to highlight the specific row in DevExpress XtraGrid depending on your task specific. 
For example, to highlight any selected row you can use the following code:

```
gridView1.Appearance.SelectedRow.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

To highlight the specific rows by using custom conditions you can use the [GridView.RowStyle](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_RowStyletopic) event:

```
void gridView1_RowStyle(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowStyleEventArgs e) {
    if((e.State & DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.GridRowCellState.Selected) != 0) {
        // check some conditions
        e.HighPriority = true;
        e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Blue;
    }
}
```

Please read more about all these approaches in the following help-article: [Customizing Appearances of Individual Rows and Cells](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument758)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
{
    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue;
}
```

Comment: I use DevExpress GridView

Comment: oops. you did not mention. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SelectedRowStyle property

[MSDN exemple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedrowstyle.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

`To change selected rows`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
            if (null != item)
            {
                item.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue;
            }
        }            
    }
```

`To change all rows`

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the gridview, set the below method for event CellFormatting

```
private void StocksDataGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e) {
    StocksDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.OrangeRed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You said you used `DevexpressGrid`. So it's can be easily achieved by changing `girdView's properties` in design time.

[image]